# Can a Board of Directors fail to disclose lawsuits against the organization?

Tags: non-profit, missouri

I recently asked my Church's representative on the Board of Directors for a High School Association that our church is a member of the following question: "Are there any lawsuits against the school?"  He responded: "If there were any, those would be handled in executive session and I would be unable to disclose them."

Obviously from a parliamentary perspective, he can not disclose information from executive session. However, lawsuits seems like something a Board of Directors ought to be required to disclose to the owners (member churches in this case).

Is there any law in Missouri or Federal law which would require disclosure of the existence of such lawsuits?

Edit: I serve as an officer in my congregation. I happen to know the lawsuit exists (I became suspicious and searched public records). I also happen to know our director has not informed anyone else as he believes he is bound by the board policy. It’s less about informing me as an individual and more about informing the governing board.

Comment: The answer probably depends on who you are. What is your connection to the church or association?

Comment: Also note that it is different to request a particular member of the Board or the Board as an entity.

Comment: I’ll edit this in when I get a different interface. I’m an officer in the congregation. I happen to know the lawsuit exists (I became suspicious and searched public records). I also happen to know our director has not informed anyone else as he believes he is bound by the board policy. It’s less about informing me as an individual and more about informing the governing board.